# Having a a large heading in coloumn headings using GWT

Tags: java, gwt, flextable

Im having trouble with writing coloumn names using a FlexTable in GWT my code is as follows:

```
public class TemplateWebInterface implements EntryPoint
{

      final protected FlexTable _templatesFlexTable  = createTable("Template Name", "Added", "Modified");

      public void onModuleLoad()
   { 
    _mainPanel.add(_templatesFlexTable);
    RootPanel.get().add(_mainPanel);

   }

}
```

So for "Template Name" I need it to come out like

```
 Template <br /> Name
```

I hope the question is understandable, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlexTable support setWidget as well as setHTML. You can use either of these for your headers.